# SQL Query on a list gives 'Error saving the Query field.Invalid column name'

Tags: sql

In Query Studio i'm trying this just to find out how to proceed further:

```
SELECT
status
,[Email Address]
,CountryCode
,LanguageCode
FROM _listSubscribers
WHERE ListID = 7989
    AND [Subscriber Key] = '00324000004nugbAAA'
```

And I get this error message:
Error saving the Query field.Invalid column name 'Subscriber Key'.

Probably something very simple but what is it?

Comment: Can you [edit] your post to clarify -- are you using the Query Studio for Marketing Cloud app from the AppExchange?

Answer (score 0):

Yup, found it, it needed ent. in front of _listSubscribers.

```sql
SELECT
status
,[Email Address]
,CountryCode
,LanguageCode
FROM ent._listSubscribers
WHERE ListID = 7989
    AND [Subscriber Key] = '00324000004nugbAAA'
```