# Escaping parenthesis in SQL Query LIKE clause

Tags: marketing-cloud, query

I'm trying to perform a SQL Query with a LIKE clause such as:

```
SELECT
    :
FROM
    mytable
    :
WHERE
    code LIKE 'SOME_ID (%'
```

to match codes like "SOME_ID (5)", "SOME_ID (63)", etc

But getting the error

```
Error saving the Query field.An unmatched parenthesis occurs in the query.
```

Assume I have to escape the parenthesis somehow, but nothing I've tried seems to be able to do so.

Tried some of the standard SQL escaping methods

```
WHERE
    code LIKE 'SOME_ID \(%'
```

and

```
WHERE
    code LIKE 'SOME_ID (()%'
```

and

```
WHERE
    code LIKE 'SOME_ID \(%' ESCAPE '\'
```

None seem to work.

How do I escape special characters/parenthesis in SFMC SQL Queries?

TIA!

Comment: Where are you attempting to create this SOQL query, as I tried a SOQL query using a single parenthesis within a LIKE clause and it worked just fine?

Comment: Is the rest of your query (your ":" ": mytable" lines) correct?

Comment: Perhaps a similar issue as https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/373058/sql-query-on-a-list-gives-error-saving-the-query-field-invalid-column-name

Comment: @PaulN this question is about Marketing Cloud and SQL, not SOQL

Comment: Are you trying this in Query Studio or Query Activity? QS is known to give some weird errors that are not found in Query Activities.

Comment: can you try using the ASCII char definition ,  `(` should be : `CHAR(40)` - reference https://theasciicode.com.ar/ascii-printable-characters/semicolon-ascii-code-59.html

Comment: @Gortonington yes, I'm trying to execute in Query Studio. Agree, QS has some odd issues not found in Query Activities. Unfortunately this particular issue occurs in a Query Activity as well.

Answer (score 6):

You can solve this by using the CHAR() function in SQL. The number for open parantheses is 40.

```sql
SELECT 
 :
FROM 
 :
WHERE field LIKE 'SOME_ID ' + CHAR(40) + '%'
```

Will look for 'SOME_ID (%' as you requested. This removes any syntax confusion the processors might be running into.

Comment: This solution did work for me. Thank you!